# nginx stub status SPIKES "writing" for a few seconds, causing 504 error. Why?! Bad VPS neighbour?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, debian, php-fpm, ddos

I am using Apache and nginx as reverse proxy, with php5-fpm. The latest week we've been receiving the following error in nginx's error.log:
upstream timed out (110 connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream.

This happened all of a sudden, without any changes from our end. When I monitor [stub status](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_stub_status_module.html) while the website is becoming slower and finally showing the 504 gateway error, the "writing" **always** spikes up from 0 til around 30-40, while "waiting" goes down to 0. Active connections spikes up from around 15-20 to 70-80. After around xx seconds it goes back to between 0-2 "writing", 18-30 "waiting" and stays like that until it's time for the freakshow again.

How come?

1) Can this be *caused* by a DDoS attack?

2) Or bad neighbours at my VPS? *grep devices /proc/cgroups* actually shows there should be 205 VPS's in total on the same server if you can trust those numbers.

I've tried understanding nginx's documentation regarding writing but I do not get it. Please explain it in more newbie friendly terms.

Hope you gurus can help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is it you expect to get from `grep devices /proc/cgroups`? This is _not_ a count of the number of containers running on a machine!

Comment: Oh really? That's what I read on a forum.

"Have you ever wonder how much containers are running on the VPS node you're at ? There is a little trick I found while browsing Reddit:

grep devices /proc/cgroups" but you are probably right. Because when I ran it within a VMWare Debian install.. It showed 64....

Comment: You can't believe everything you read on the Internet. :) I just started a single container on a host and came up with `devices 11 75 1`.

Comment: Haha damn it. Would be an easy fix otherwise to maybe migrate to a dedicated server.

Comment: To be fair, it _probably_ is caused by host overcommitment of some type or another.

Comment: Thanks for your input, appreciate it. But when I check out the hardware monitor, "htop", it doesnt show the RAM or CPU cores spike up. It's all normal over there. Wouldnt this be the case then, in a VPS enviroment? Or what am I missing here :D Sorry, I am a newbie.